# dual boot of ubuntu and win7

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I'm intrested in installing ubuntu 12.04 parallel to windows 7(basic).
I read all the posts in the forum about it, installing ubuntu alongside.

I am allocating 100 Gb Hard drive space for ubuntu. Will the swap be created automatically? or do I need to create it manually.

And about grub : Whether ubuntu will take control of booting, or else i need to install third party software...?

Comment: It depends upon the type of installation you select.If it is manual then manual allocation of swap.If you let ubuntu do the automatic partion then install then Ubuntu will do it for you

Comment: @Stormvirux would the Ubuntu installation automatically create a swap partition or a swap file? user171329 do you have a preference? There are quite a few resources on the web about choosing one and setting it up.

Comment: @Stormvirux I mean which of the two would it create? A partition or file?

Comment: The automated Ubuntu installation will automatically create a swap partition. I checked it again on my system using "gparted".

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of Ubuntu.

IMHO, manually configuring the installation gives granular control. But, if you are not confident, then go for automated install.

regarding swap --- For manual install, before booting from the Ubuntu live CD, create a small partition for swap and another partition for Ubuntu (of whatever size you wish to have).
While installing, select the last option box (which is meant for manual install).
When it asks to select partitions, specify the small one for swap. (and do not forget to specify the correct mount point).
For automated install, you need not do anything for it.

regarding grub -- do not worry about it. Ubuntu installer will take care of it.

HTH